# Traits and classes: worried about length of class

Tags: php, performance, design-patterns, standards

I am working on a web application in which I want registered users can access everything related to their account via a single class (member)

Like:

```
example.com/controller_class/action_name

example.com/member/my-profile,
example.com/member/edit-profile,
example.com/member/my-orders,
example.com/member/mybooks,
example.com/member/my-book-requests,
example.com/member/my-notes,
example.com/member/my-notes-requests
```

and so.

I am using traits in my PHP classes with having 500-600 lines in each trait. Now I am worried about the class length to compile. I have used 6-7 traits (or can be more in future) in a single class, and class code becomes around 5000 lines. Is there any effect on performance during compilation of class or any drawback of following such approach.

Style which I am following:

```
trait Profile {
    ...
}

trait books {
    ...
}

trait Services {
    ...
}
```

etc., and  the main class is:

```
require_once 'traits/trait.Common.php';
require_once 'traits/trait.profile.php';
require_once 'traits/trait.books.php';
require_once 'traits/trait.services.php';
require_once 'traits/trait.notes.php';
require_once 'traits/trait.Account.php';

class MemberController extends LoggedUserController {
use Common, profile, books, services, notes, Account;
...
}
```

If I am on a wrong way, could you please suggest to me the best way to accomplish the same?
Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question which includes my code too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual impact on parsing performance should be negligible. However, purely from a design standpoint, you should split this up into multiple classes and use *composition*, or the [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

> he composite pattern describes that a group of objects is to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object. The intent of a composite is to "compose" objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. Implementing the composite pattern lets clients treat individual objects and compositions uniformly.

So, instead of traits, things like the "profile" should be objects of a class called `MemberProfile`, instantiated with information for this particular member. Inside `Member`, you could access something from the profile via `$this->profile->getName();` or `$this->profile->name;`, for example.

Here's a quick example:

```
<?php

require_once 'MemberProfile.php';
require_once 'MemberAccount.php';

class MemberController extends LoggedUserController
{
    public $profile;
    public $account;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $memberId = $_GET['memberId'];

        $this->profile = new MemberProfile($memberId);
        $this->account = new MemberAccount($memberId);
    }

    public function display()
    {
        $accountBalance = $this->account->getBalance();
        $fullName = $this->profile->getFullName();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, check above :)

Comment: Thanks Will for your quick response but one question is still in my mind

I have not in requirement of all objects at every time. Some times I need profile information, some times books- requests etc... then why I will create object for all included classes...

Comment: As my main concern related with the performance on application during class compilation of such a big file.

As I understand both traits and composite both are same but we can access members and function 

1) with their respective object (in example you have posted above) and,
2) in traits with $this object

and the only benefit is that we can define the functions with same name in different classes as we can not in traits.

Comment: Right, I'd say that's accurate. There should not be any performance penalty, but the design using Traits may be harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Will for your quick response but one question is still in my mind I have not in requirement of all objects at every time. Some times I need profile information, some times books- requests etc... then why I will create object for all included classes...